# How to put common validation to all views?

Tags: python, pyramid

I have `view_xx.py` and `view_yy.py` and I also have a common views.py.
I want to put a validation for checking that `request.page_size` is less than or equal to `request.registry.settings["max_page_size"]`.

How do I do this?
Is it possible using contexts in a common views.py file?

I am not sure how to put a context such that it first goes to `view_xx.py` depending on URL and then goes to common views function to validate page size and then again comes back to the `view_xx.py` view for further steps.

Comment: Have you considered using a mixin?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to perform that check when setting/computing `request.page_size`.